# Начал изучать Питон в pycharm. Столкнулся с проблемой

Tags: python, python-3.x, обработка-ошибок

Начал с изучения функций, написал код:

```
def g(x, y):   
    return (y* *4 + 4* *x

g(2, 3)
print(g)
```

вывело это:

> <function g at 0x00C385C8> 
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Ваша функция и так возвращает результат, зачем print?

Comment: Поискал в инете, было сказано, что в pycharm нужно самому ручками говорить программе, чтобы вывела результат

Comment: а проблема-то в чем?

Comment: print (g(2, 3))

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, в этом была причина

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def g(x, y):   
    return (y**4 + 4**x)

print(g(2, 3))
```

Выводится 97

1. Забыл закрывающую скобку в

```
    return (y**4 + 4**x)
```

2. Твоя функция **возвращает** результат, по этому надо писать

```
    print(g(2, 3))
```

3. "<function g at 0x00C385C8>" это id функции.

Comment: это не id, а адрес